# Spring -> Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I get the following error when executing "java -jar .."

```
2017-05-04 21:40:41.494  INFO 7808 --- [           main] es.wolfis.KanguruApplication             : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-05-04 21:40:41.518  INFO 7808 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@28ac3dc3: startup date [Thu May 04 21:40:41 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-04 21:40:41.674  INFO 7808 --- [           main] o.s.s.a.AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : No TaskExecutor bean found for async annotation processing.
2017-05-04 21:40:41.681  WARN 7808 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
2017-05-04 21:40:41.683 ERROR 7808 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133) ~[kanguru.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[kanguru.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[kanguru.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [kanguru.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [kanguru.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [kanguru.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [kanguru.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [kanguru.jar:na]
        at es.wolfis.KanguruApplication.main(KanguruApplication.java:12) [kanguru.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:185) ~[kanguru.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:158) ~[kanguru.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130) ~[kanguru.jar:na]
        ... 8 common frames omitted
```

I am using intellij IDEA and my pom.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>es.wolfis</groupId>
<artifactId>kanguru</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>kanguru</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <start-class>es.wolfis.KanguruApplication</start-class>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.53</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have created the directory resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: es.wolfis.KanguruApplication
```

And my main file contains the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"es.wolfis.*"})
public class KanguruApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(KanguruApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

Any idea what might be going on?
Thanks!!

Comment: Does your code run ok from IDE?

Comment: Yes, @IvanPronin from the IDE works correctly

Comment: Remove the manifest and why do you have a provided tomcat dependency when you are using Jetty? And you probably want `spring-boot-starter-web` with an excluded `spring-boot-starter-tomcat`.

Comment: You should also remove the `@ComponentScan` from the `KanguruApplication` and your `jackson-databind` dependency from the pom (assuming you have added `spring-boot-starter-web` as a dependency).

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum !! It works perfectly. Actually, I have a mess with all of Maven's dependencies. Thanks for your help